# IIS giving 503 Service Unavailable error after port change

Tags: port, iis

I've changed the listening port on IIS to `4016`, and getting an odd problem.

Whenever I try to browse to the server with a web browser, I am now getting a "503 Service Unavailable" error.

The strange thing is:
I don't get this error if I refer to the server as "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" (i.e. http://localhost:4016/ or http://127.0.0.1:4016/ are OK)

But I *do* get it if I use the IP address of the server (i.e. http://192.168.246.20:4016 displays the error), either from another PC on the network or the server itself. This is the IP address of the server.

I also *don't* get the error in either case, if I have IIS listen on port 80.

- I've allowed port 4016 on the firewall
- I've checked the Application Pool is still running
- I've checked the Event log (Windows Logs/Application or System), but no entry is displayed when this error is thrown.
- I've checked the Access log and enabled the Failed Request Tracing but again, no entry is displayed for the error in either.
- I've made sure that IIS is the only thing listening on Port 4016 (using `netstat`, and also if I stop IIS, the attempt to browse times out)
- I've tried disabling the firewall to ensure that's not the issue, but with the same result.
- Windows 7

Any ideas?

**Update**

I tried with another port (40163) and it works fine! Unfortunately for my purposes it has to be port 4016. Is there a way of checking why a particular port would be causing a problem?

Comment: You might also want to enable the access logs.

Comment: The Windows Firewall? Have you allowed the port or the application on the Firewall?  If only the port, allow the application instead and drop a comment @Fabby

Comment: As a simple test to rule out the FW, disable it entirely for a moment and then test to connection the port. This will tell you if the FW is blocking the traffic if you disable it "entirely" and then you can access the site without localhost

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - Just tried that, and same result (this would also seem to answer @Fabby)

Comment: @arieljannai - Did this, but no entry appears in the access log for the failing request. (Entries do appear for successful ones though)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the hostname and the port in the site bindings.
Sites -> "Your Web Site" -> Edit Site -> Bindings

Comment: This seems to help alright - I set the hostname to 192.168.246.20 and it now works for `http://192.168.246.20:4016` - but now it doesn't work for `http://localhost:4016`! I might get away with that though... It also doesn't explain why it worked fine for port `80` and `40163` though...

Comment: you can add more hostnames in the site bindings. Do that for localhost and all other IPs/ Hostnames you want to reach over that port.